# Problema em IF JavaScript retornando valor maior como se fosse menor

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma lógica para armazenar números em variáveis (A, B e C) e depois verificar quais são os números maiores e quais são os números menores. Depois dessa verificação eu dou o console.log e escrevo o resultado na tela.

Até então estava indo tudo bem mas quando eu coloco valores maiores que 9 misturados com valores menores que 9 o resultado que sai na tela é que o número maior é menor do que o número menor.

Exemplo:

var a = 9;

var b = 11;

var c = 5;

O resultado que me retorna é: 11 < 5 < 9;

O resultado que eu quero é: 5 < 9 < 11.

Meu código HTML:

```
<body>
    <fomr>
        <fieldset>

            <div class="form-single">
                <label>Número da var "A" :</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" id="valorA"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-single">
                <label>Número da var "b" :</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" id="valorB"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-single">
                <label>Número da var "c" :</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" id="valorC"/>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="variaveis()"/>
        </fieldset>
    </fomr>

    <div class="result-content" id="result"></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Meu código JS:

```
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
    var d;
    
    a = document.getElementById("valorA").value;
    b = document.getElementById("valorB").value;
    c = document.getElementById("valorC").value;
    parseInt(a);
    parseInt(b);
    parseInt(c);
    
    if(a < b && b < c) {
        a = a;
        b = b;
        c = c;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c;
        console.log("Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c);
    } 
    if (b < a && a < c) {
        d = a;
        a = b;
        b = d;
        c = c;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c;
        console.log("Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c)
    } 
    if (c < a && a < b) {
        d = a;
        a = c;
        c = b;
        b = d;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c;
        console.log("Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c)
    } 
    if (b < c && c < a) {
        d = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c;
        console.log("Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c)
    } 
    if (c < b && b < a) {
        d = c;
        c = a;
        a = d;
        b = b;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c;
        console.log("Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c)
    } 
    if(a < c && c < b) {
        d = b;
        a = a;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c;
        console.log("Valor de 'a': " + a + " valor de 'b': " + b + " valor de 'c': " + c)
    }
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134692/discussion-on-question-by-willian-raniere-problema-em-if-javascript-retornando)

Answer (score -3):

as variaveis **a, b, c** estão recebendo valores **não numéricos**, use o **perseint()** para transformar o valor em um número inteiro.

```
"6"<"7" --> False

 6 < 7  --> True
```

use:

```
   x = parseInt(document.getElementById("valorX").value);
```